# If conditions in SQL

Tags: sql, mariadb

Clarification. I want to have a query that finds me the row with newest Timestamp, but if that row has column deleted set to 1 then I want to get back NULL. That is what I am trying to do.

I would like to make a query with sub query in WHERE clause something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM table WHERE ts > 'x' ORDER BY ts LIMIT 1)
```

But the thing is there is a column called `DELETED` in table, and if `DELETED = 1` I would like to get just this

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE id = NULL
```

How could I do that?

I am working with **MariaDB**, but any SQL would help.

Comment: Tag the DBMS product which are you using (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server ... etc.). "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  A column doesn't have a single value, it has a value for every row, so your description doesn't make sense.

Comment: It would be better if you can add the available data and desired result. Question needs better clarification

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want the "DELETED" result if there is any. Else you want the row with a ts greater than x. Assuming that "DELETED is 0 if not 1, you can use Gordons SQL like this:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE (t.ts > 'x' or t.deleted = 1)
ORDER BY t.deleted desc, t.ts
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: If "id" is not unique, put the OR clause in your subquery

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is related to your question, but why not just execute the query as:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE t.ts > 'x'
ORDER BY t.ts
LIMIT 1;
```

It seems simpler than your version of the query -- assuming that `id` is unique in the table.

Comment: There is a difference if `id` is not unique in `table`.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM table WHERE ts > 'x' ORDER BY ts LIMIT 1)
AND deleted = 0;
```